# delta hedging with stochastic volatility

Tags: stochastic-volatility, black-scholes-merton

In my thesis I want to work with delta hedging with stochastic volatility using Black-Scholes model. How will you suggest I implement numerical solutions using data from the real world? Beside Monte Carlo, which numerical solutions will be useful?

Comment: Re the real world question, could you find volatility as a function of time, and compute the standard deviation and mean (assuming the histogram result looks something like a normal or other recognizable distribution?)